# A weak property in Objective-C class implementing a Swift protocol

Tags: swift, weak-references, swift-protocols, swift4.1

In Swift 4.1, weak properties have been [deprecated in protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0186-remove-ownership-keyword-support-in-protocols.md), since the compiler has no way to enforce it. It is the responsibility of the class conforming to the protocol to define the memory behaviour of the property.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
  // weak var myProperty: OtherProtocol /* Illegal in Swift 4.1 */
  var myProperty: OtherProtocol? { get set }
} 
@objc protocol OtherProtocol: class {}
```

However, this gets exported to `MyProject-Swift.h` as a strong property:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <OtherProtocol> _Nullable myProperty;
@end
```

And now I have an issue when the conforming class is written in Objective-C:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject<MyProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <OtherProtocol> myProperty;
@end
```

The error states `retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'myProperty' does not match the property inherited`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that this will be (re)allowed in Swift 4.2 for `@objc` protocols: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/15274. Until then, you'll have to implement the protocol in Obj-C.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks! Unbelievable that no-one saw this issue before it was released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is indeed the strong reference in the generated `-Swift.h` file.
I found out that you can still mark the property as weak by adding `@objc weak` before the property, so it gets generated correctly in the Swift header *and* not trigger the Swift 4.1 deprecation warning.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
  // weak var myProperty: OtherProtocol /* Illegal in Swift 4.1 */
  @objc weak var myProperty: OtherProtocol? { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Hamish's comment, a livable workaround until Swift 4.2 solves the issue, that doesn't force to rewrite the protocol in Objective-C and has a limited impact, would be to use clang's diagnostics pragma instruction.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject<MyProtocol>
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <OtherProtocol> myProperty;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
@end
```